# Axis Label centered in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a custom chart  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nagoba/Baeqm/)
I have set label property as

```
labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value);
            },
                align:'center',
            x:150
        }
```

I have a linked axis which shows year.
What I want is the axis label should be in center of the two extremes as in image.

[image]

what I have done now is, I have given x:150 to label.but that wont work if I resize the browser window.
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I found it.

Instead of using static values,

I used useHTML, and positioned labels by CSS styles.

```
 labels: {
            useHTML:true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<span class="label">'+Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value)+'</span>';
            }
        }
```

Simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Baeqm/1/)